# After rebooting motorola defy M525 no service network shows?

Tags: locked-out, motorola-defy

After several attempts of pattern my motorola defy mb525 has been blocked and asking for my goggle account and password but then when finished entering my account and password it will restart automatically but the problems is still there.. So i tried to reboot my motorola defy mb525 but after rebooting, the service network is gone. No more signal in any GSM network...Please somebody help me about this problem. how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your service provider. Some cell companies lock the phone after failed attempts as a precaution to possible theft.

Comment: ok thank you for your idea but my simcard if i inserted it to other mobile it has service network only in my motorola defy after rebooting.